# How to add/subtract with Mongoose-long?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose-long for large numbers.  I'm not sure I am using it correctly.  I set the value...

```
 user = new User({val:12345678901234});
```

val is mongoose.Schema.Types.Long

1)  What is the correct way to show val, toString()?

2)  So how do I manipulate (add, subtract) this value?  Javascript doesn't support full 64bit values, so do I have to do this through mongodb's $inc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use `$inc` to atomically manipulate the value in the stored docs, but outside of `update` operations you can use the methods of [`Long`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html):

```
var sum = user.val.add(123);
console.log(sum.toString());
```